# Elastic Search with json field and priority with other field and filter data on top

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I am going to search using elastic search Engine with some selected field priory. Currently, I have the following query for searching selected field (cna == City Name) for "lon" not a priority with limit 10.

I want to add cna (cnm == Country Name) field to filter on top for "lon" search term and then load another match list.

```
http://{{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}}/rezproduction@@city/city/_search?default_operator=AND&q=cna:lon*&size=10
```

I have added my sample source json here.

```
{ rid   "3"
    aid "0"
    rnm "North America"
    anm ""
    cid "12051"
    cnid    "55"
    cncd    "US"
    sbid    ""
    sid "50"
    lat "46.35564"
    lon "-124.05565"
    index   0
    type    "City"
    google  "N"
    cna "Long Beach"
    cnm "USA"
    sna "Washington"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for above question.

```
http://{{ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}}/rezproduction@@city/city/_search?default_operator=AND&q=(cna:lon* AND cnm:{{Country Name which is priority}}) OR (cna:lon*)&size=10
```

I have add additional query parameter with **AND** condition for the priority column name. Here I have used **Country Name** field for the priority.